# Unexpected reserved word 'private'. (13:4)? Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint

Hello for some reason my eslint spits this out on me.

[image: Error]
Lines 12-14

```
  constructor(
    private readonly box2D: typeof Box2D & EmscriptenModule,
    private readonly helpers: Helpers,
```

Here is how I import code because in reality the file is not a js file but a ts file.
`import { CanvasDebugDraw } from "./scripts/debugDraw";`

[image]

Here is the file structure if you will need it for what ever reason.

Honestly have no clue what can be causing this error because I don't even have eslint setup all of the references to it are in package.json here they are.

```json
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
```

Comment: I had same problem for keyword "interface" and I fixed that by adding ts-standard in my package.json

"ts-standard": {
    "project": "./tsconfig.json"
  }

and consider installing that as devDependency

Comment: You need to add typescript plugin in the eslint config. https://typescript-eslint.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that webpack automatically compiles ts to js however something was causing an error in webpack causing the file to not compile properly, luckily fix is just restarting the session.